# Missing "options" button in Joomla! update component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm trying to migrate from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3. To do so, i follow Joomla 2.5 to 3.x Step by Step Migration on docs.joomla.org. But i have a weird problem that i fail to solve by myself.

There is step:
Go to Components → Joomla Update. (It should say no updates found. If it doesn’t, update Joomla to the latest version and test. Then do another backup.) **Click on the Options button at the top right corner.**
Problem is, i have no Options button shown there. [image]
Can somebody explain me why? And what should i do?
I tried to clear cache of browser, purge cache in control panel and reinstalled stable Joomla 2.5 package. Problem was present. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the options button is missing but you can browse to the Joomla Update Component options directly via:

http://yourwebsite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=com_joomlaupdate

Once you have updated to Joomla 3.x hopefully the option button will reappear.

Comment: I figured out, that my backend user profile lost it's superuser permissions during one of the automatic updates, adding group manually into db showed me options button . Thanks a lot, with help of your link a got an error which lead me to determine the problem.